# Is it possible to repeat non-header column data after row is split by pagebreak?

Tags: c#, html, page-break, nested-table

I have a `<table>` where each `<tr>` consists of a  `<td>` containing a group identifier and a `<td colspan="3">` that contains an additional `<table>` with the many details for that particular group. My issue is that when the table is printed and a row in the main table is unavoidably split I get an empty "Group Name" column on the following page. Like so...

> `#####################################################################`
> `|Group Name|     Detail 1    |    Detail 2     |     Detail 3       |`
> `#####################################################################`
> `|  Name 1  |Detail 1.A       |Detail 2.A       |Detail 3.A          |`
> `|          |_________________|_________________|____________________|`
> `|          |Detail 1.B       |Detail 2.B       |Detail 3.B          |`
> `|          |_________________|_________________|____________________|`
> `|          |Detail 1.C       |Detail 2.C       |Detail 3.C          |`
> `|          |_________________|_________________|____________________|`
>
> `#####################################################################`
> `|Group Name|     Detail 1    |    Detail 2     |     Detail 3       |`
> `#####################################################################`
> `|          |Detail 1.D       |Detail 2.D       |Detail 3.D          |`
> `|          |_________________|_________________|____________________|`
> `|          |Detail 1.E       |Detail 2.E       |Detail 3.E          |`
> `|__________|_________________|_________________|____________________|`
> `|  Name 2  |Detail 1.A       |Detail 2.A       |Detail 3.A          |`
> `|          |_________________|_________________|____________________|`
> `|          |Detail 1.B       |Detail 2.B       |Detail 3.B          |`
> `|          |_________________|_________________|____________________|`
> `|          |Detail 1.C       |Detail 2.C       |Detail 3.C          |`
> `|          |_________________|_________________|____________________|`

Is there a way to get the value of the "Group Name" row to be repeated after the page-break so it looks like this?

> `#####################################################################`
> `|Group Name|     Detail 1    |    Detail 2     |     Detail 3       |`
> `#####################################################################`
> `| Name 1   |Detail 1.A       |Detail 2.A       |Detail 3.A          |`
> `|          |_________________|_________________|____________________|`
> `|          |Detail 1.B       |Detail 2.B       |Detail 3.B          |`
> `|          |_________________|_________________|____________________|`
> `|          |Detail 1.C       |Detail 2.C       |Detail 3.C          |`
> `|          |_________________|_________________|____________________|`
>
> `#####################################################################`
> `|Group Name|     Detail 1    |    Detail 2     |     Detail 3       |`
> `#####################################################################`
> `|  Name 1  |Detail 1.D       |Detail 2.D       |Detail 3.D          |`
> `|          |_________________|_________________|____________________|`
> `|          |Detail 1.E       |Detail 2.E       |Detail 3.E          |`
> `|__________|_________________|_________________|____________________|`
> `|  Name 2  |Detail 1.A       |Detail 2.A       |Detail 3.A          |`
> `|          |_________________|_________________|____________________|`
> `|          |Detail 1.B       |Detail 2.B       |Detail 3.B          |`
> `|          |_________________|_________________|____________________|`
> `|          |Detail 1.C       |Detail 2.C       |Detail 3.C          |`
> `|          |_________________|_________________|____________________|`

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT**
When I say the main table is "unavoidably split" I mean that there are groups with so many details that they cannot be contained on a single page. So even if these groups were to be the first row on a page they would still spill over onto additional pages and the "Group Name" column would be split.

Comment: I'd say the obvious answer here is "yes", but there is not enough information to advise how.  How is the main table "unavoidably split"?  What are you using to print the table?

Comment: What I mean is that some "Group Name" rows have so many details applied to them they cannot be contained on a single page. So even if that row is the first one on the page it will still spill over to additional pages.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems in the past with printing HTML.

I've not come across a way to achieve exactly what you want, but as an alternative suggestion, you could try the css style `page-break-inside: avoid` on each `<tr>` tag, so discourage page breaks within a row. Thus if a row is going to split over two pages, the page break should actually occur before the row, thus avoiding the issue. Not breaking the row across pages may even be preferable?

Link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp

NB it's been a while since I played with this, but I do recall older versions of IE not wanting to play ball... you might needs to test across multiple browsers!

Comment: My issues is that some rows are so big they cannot be contained on a single page so they'll have to be split. While I'm writing this to be used in IE8(not my choice) I do test in FF and Chrome with the same results.

Comment: Hmm, in that case I'm not aware of a pure CSS solution, certainly. If you know your page size and printable area (a potentially big if, I know) you could calculate where your page breaks are likely to be in javascript/jQuery, and then add in extra absolutely-positioned titles in the group column. You could put these in a css class with @media print on them so they only appear on the print and not on-screen. Possibly problem-prone solution though!

Comment: I'll look into that but it might be more trouble than its worth. This isn't a "must", its more me trying to appease my own pet-peeves. It seems like there has to be a solution, but after hours and hours of online searching I feel like I'm the first and only person to have this issue.

Comment: If it's any consolation, I had this problem years ago, in an environment where breaking the rows was a big deal (could cause information to be misread which could have resulted in patient safety issues). This was in the days before StackOverflow! Had no great solution then either. The only sure-fire way, I believe, is to have some awareness of the sizes of what you're printing and the media you're printing it to. There's no true "auto" way using the likes of HTML/CSS. Some third-party HTML-to-PDF libraries include various clever means to do this sort of thing, but it is a ****-ache.